# .Net How to get notified efficiently when a thread is suspended?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, pinvoke

Does anyone know a way to get notified when a specific thread is being suspended and resumed?

I would like to be able to to something like this:

```
thread.Suspended += delegate
{
    //Do something
};

thread.Resumed += delegate
{
    //Do something else
};
```

I doubt that the .Net Framework has this capability, but is there a technique to achieve this maybe with pinvoke? I need it to be possible with low overhead.

Comment: Why do you want to know?  What scenario are you trying to enable?

Comment: I'm trying to tweak a ThreadPool to have one active thread per cpu. It would try has much as possible to keep only one thread per cpu in the pool and would create new threads only when one of its active threads is blocked.

Comment: What if you create another thread, and the previously blocked one wakes up again? Sounds like you are trying to micromanage cat herding to me.

Comment: Nice metaphor, this is probably unmanageable like you say, I'll just forget about this crazy idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're committed to writing your own thread pool this probably doesn't help, but I'd try to stick with the .NET ThreadPool class and tune it as required with SetMaxThreads/SetMinThreads and GetMaxThreads/GetAvailableThreads. Is there any particular reason why this isn't good enough?

I was at PDC last year and attended some of Joe Duffy's talks on parallelism were quite interesting. I recall he was talking about providing an extensible thread pool class in .NET since MSFT generally find that when people go and write their own thread pools they'll work fine most of the time, but get caught out in edge cases by various gotchas. By providing an extensibility mechanism they were hoping to limit the potential for devs to get caught out.

Comment: The .Net ThreadPool is good enough, it will add a thread to its pool only when a work item has been queued for more than one second. I was just experimenting for fun if it is possible for a thread pool to create new threads only when one of its thread has done a blocking operation, but I guess this is unmanageable.

Answer (score 0):

Windows has no such notification mechanism for Thread.Suspend/Thread.Resume  You should not be using Thread.Suspend/Thread.Resume - it can easily lead to deadlocks and other hard to find bugs.  Use the normal synchronization primitives (locks, events, etc.) to cause a thread to block until it has work to do.

UPDATE:

You could enable [context switch events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964744(VS.85).aspx) in ETW and consume them via [ProcessTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364093(VS.85).aspx).  OldThreadId and OldThreadState will tell why a thread stopped running (transition to ready, standby, waiting, etc., etc.).  NewThreadId will tell you when a thread starts running.  You will have to process events for *every* context switch in the system.  It will be incredibly high volume, consume a lot of CPU in your process, and be very difficult to get precisely right.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not talking about using Thread.Suspend() or Thread.Resume(), I just want to get notified when a thread is suspended (by the scheduler or by a blocking operation). I wish there was a hack to be able to do this.